# I want to store input value in a var and show in HTML empty <p></p> using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to store an input value in a variable and show it in an existing, currently empty `<p>` tag, using jQuery. My current code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>


<script type="text/jquery-2">
    $(function(){
        $("#input_name")#submit(function){
            var value = $("input_name").val();
            $('#p').text.value();
        });
    });
</script>



<form>
    <input type="text" id="input_name" size="10" maxlength="10" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<p id="P">

</p>
```

Comment: You can use $('#p').text(value);

Comment: The question is very basic and I think you should read jQuery docs first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your code to following:

**HTML**

```
<form id="my-form">
    <input type="text" id="input_name" size="10" maxlength="10" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(function(){
    // you should give id to form that is to be submitted.
    // you had syntax error here. missing ) after function 
    $("#my-form").submit(function(e) { // change # to .
        var value = $("#input_name").val(); // you should have #input_name

        $('#p').text(value); // text function takes value as parameter
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Here is your working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/subash1232/f12bgLpz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You're using `$.text()` incorrectly. Change

```
$('#p').text.value();
```

to

```
$('#p').text(value);
```

Your code to catch the submit action also has syntax errors. It should be:

```
$(function(){
    $("form").submit(function){
        var value = $("input_name").val();
        $('#p').text(value);
    });
});
```

Note changes in the second line. The `<form>` has a submit event, not the input field. Also, it's `$(selector).submit(...)`, not `$(selector)#submit)`.

I would highly recommend that you read a basic JavaScript tutorial, then a basic jQuery tutorial, and use an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>


<script type="text/jquery-2">
   $("#form").submit(function(){
      var val = $("#input_name").val();
      $("#p").html(val);
      return false;
   });
</script>



<form id="form" >
    <input type="text" id="input_name" size="10" maxlength="10" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<p id="p">

</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the change(will work when the input losses focus) or keyup(will happen every keystroke) events. if you want to do it on the button click, then create a click event, or use the on_submit of the form to call a method(named).

To Store the text into a var, you are using the right statement but I would suggest you avoid using value as the name of your variable.

then you have to use

```
$('#P').text(value);
```

I created a simple example with what you want to do here [on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c06kb3nL/)

```
  <form>
        <input type="text" id="input_name" size="10" maxlength="10" />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />

        </form>

    <p id="P">

    </p>
<script>
  $(function(){
  //can also use .change instead of keyup, but that will work until the input losses focus
        $("#input_name").keyup(function (){
            var input_text = $('#input_name').val();
            alert(input_text);
            $('#P').text(input_text);

        });
    });
</script>`
```